# An integral equality with respect to Gamma function

Tags: integration, gamma-function

How to prove that
$$\int_0^{\infty}\biggl(\frac{r}{1+r^2}\biggr)^q\frac{1}{r^{1+\alpha}}dr=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{q+\alpha}{2})\Gamma(\frac{q-\alpha}{2})}{2\Gamma(q)}\quad?$$

Comment: You must take care that this is true provided that $\Re(\alpha +q)>0\land \Re(q)>\Re(\alpha )$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $t=\frac {r^2} {1+r^2}$, and thus $r=\sqrt{\frac{t}{1-t}}$
$$\begin{split}
\int_0^{\infty}\biggl(\frac{r}{1+r^2}\biggr)^q\frac{1}{r^{1+\alpha}}dr &= \int_0^1 t^q t^{-\frac {q+1+\alpha}{2}}(1-t)^{\frac{q+1+\alpha}{2}}\frac 1 2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}(1-t)^{\frac 3 2}}dt\\
&=\frac 1 2\int_0^1t^{\frac{q-\alpha}{2}-1}(1-t)^{\frac {q+\alpha}2-1}dt\\
&=\frac 1 2B\left(\frac{q-\alpha}2,\frac{q+\alpha}2\right)\\
\end{split}$$
where $B$ is the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). To conclude, use the [known identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_to_the_gamma_function) (whose proof can be found following that link):
$$B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$

Comment: Let $t=\frac{1}{1+r^2}$ also works.